# Where does this convention come from? Green = right, red = wrong

Tags: conventions

Red indicates that something is wrong and requires attention/fixing. green indicates success. Where does this convention come from? I can think of traffic lights, but that's it.

example:

[image: check marks]

Comment: This might help? [Color Emotion Naming Convention Standard?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/78775/color-emotion-naming-convention-standard)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Origin of "big green button"?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34551/origin-of-big-green-button)

Comment: -1 for assuming the convention exists without providing any context of where it exists or which users it applies to.  For example, [red symbolizes good fortune or joy in Chinese culture](http://qiharmony.com/significance-of-red-gold-in-chinese-culture/).  Please consider editing your post to clarify its context and scope.

Answer (score 6):

Red color has been psychologically associated to danger. Fire and Blood are some of the things that might have triggered this response to red.

http://www.color-wheel-pro.com/color-meaning.html

https://www.quora.com/Why-is-red-colour-associated-with-danger

Also, red light is least scattered and can be seen from really long distances. So, they were used both for danger and stop signals. Later, yellow and green were introduced in traffic lights. Follow the link below to know the history of how they were chosen.

http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2012/03/the-origin-of-the-green-yellow-and-red-color-scheme-for-traffic-lights/

These metaphors were slowly adopted into graphic and UI design for wrong and right. Red - Stop - Wrong. Green - Go - Right.